# Field annotated with @Transient updated in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an entity that looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Candidate {

...
  @Transient
  private JobApplication mostRecentApplication
...
}

@Entity
public class JobApplication{
...
  @ManyToOne
  private Candidate candidate;
...
}
```

In order to eliminate a circular reference when returning the `Candidate` as a json object, I set the `Candidate` to `null` on the `JobApplication` contained within the `Candidate`. However, when I persist a `Candidate` that has been updated like this, it updates the `JobApplication` with a `null` `Candidate`, killing the association. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I was under the impression that JPA providers should ignore fields annotated with `@Transient.` I'm using Hibernate with Spring Data.

Comment: if you set the candidate as null on a transactional context, the changes will be commited to database

Answer (score 0):

> I set the `Candidate` to `null` on the `JobApplication` contained within `Candidate`.

The thing is you're free to change the value of `mostRecentApplication` to whatever you want, but changing the properties of that existing relationship could have adverse effects.

```
// change value to null
candidate.setMostRecentApplication( null );
// change value to a detached instance
candidate.setMostRecentApplication( new JobApplication(...) );
```

But if you do the following, you can observe what you see

```
candidate.getMostRecentApplication().setSomeProperty( null );
```

In this case, you're not changing `mostRecentApplication` but instead you're altering the state of `someProperty` of the `mostRecentApplication`.  If `mostRecentApplication` isn't a detached and unmanaged instance, then the value will be changed if inside a transactional context.